# I cannot logged into my Chromebook. I am able to log into Gmail

Tags: google-account, chromebook

I had to reset my password for my Google Account.  I am able to login into my Gmail.  However, I cannot log into my Chromebook.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get into my Chromebook?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you're on wifi, and that your wireless can connect to the internet. If not, your chromebook won't be able to get to Google's servers to see your new password. In that case, your old password might work until you're online again.

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions

Comment: I don't understand how this is off-topic. OP had an issue, I provided a solution (which just _happened_ to be right). What is off topic about this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I was the admin of the chromebook.  The password on the chromebook didn't match my new Google password.  I logged into the Chromebook with my old password, it then prompted me to enter my new password.

However, I'm not sure what I would have done if I lost the password to the chromebook.  I do not see away to reset/retreive it.